# Railstutorial 6.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an issue: when I type `User.new` in the rails console --sandbox it does not give me the results expected from the tutorial.  It just gives a bunch of lines of text that I do not understand.  I have done everything else in the tutorial and was able to follow along, until now.  I have no idea why this does not work.

ps: `user.rb` only contains:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

which is what the tutorial shows.

```
from -e:1:in `<main>'>> User.new
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):9
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Comment: try moving "end" to next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base end
```

To this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

Or this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Ruby expects a statement separator between the class name and the `end`; either a newline or a semicolon will work.

Comment: It is actually the second one you listed.  It just copied over wrong.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are saying this is solved or not.  If solved, give checkmark for answer, otherwise, edit your original post with the correct contents for `user.rb` as it is hard for us to help if we do not know if we are looking at your actual code.